# Mistake in an exercise (checking)

Tags: measure-theory

this is other exercise that I found. I think it can't be possible to prove that inequality is strict and again is poorly written because there is no way to know that $C$ is real and not extended real.

> Let $(X,\mathscr A, \mu)$ a measure space with positive measure and let $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions. Suppose that there exists a $C>0$ such that $\int |f_n| d\mu <C$ for all $n$. Show that if $f_n\to f$ pointwise then $f$ is integrable and $\int |f| d\mu <C$

Since $f_n\to f$, $f$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable and $|f_n|\to |f|$. By Fatou's lemma $$\int |f| d\mu = \int \liminf|f_n| d\mu\le \liminf \int|f_n| d\mu \le C$$

I believe there is a mistake in the strict inequality. For example take $C=1$ and $f_n = \chi_{[2^{-n}, 1]}$, $f=\chi_{(0.1]}$ and $\mu=\lambda$, i.e., the Lebesgue measure. Then $f_n\to f$, $\int |f_n| d\lambda =1-2^{-n}<1$ for all $n$. But $\int |f| \lambda=1=C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is whether you can claim the strict inequality in the limit then the answer is no, you can't (and your suspicion is well justified).

Answer (score 1):

Take $\forall n\geq 1: f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},x\mapsto 1-1/n$. Then $\forall n: \int f_n =1-1/n<1=:C$, but $\int \lim f_n=1$. Of course, $C$ is assumed to be not sharp, then the strict inequality follows.

By the way, since the conclusion states that $f$ is integrable, then that means $C$ is taken to be real, otherwise the inequality would be redundant.

Comment: Oh, I just saw you already gave  a counterexample, sorry about that.